# Enable switchable graphics amd/amd

Tags: drivers, 16.10, amd-graphics, switchable-graphics

I am using an MSI GX60-3AE notebook with an A10-5750m APU with integrated 8650G (VLIW4) and a discrete 7970m (GCN1.0).

I've installed ubuntu 16.10 then realized that the official drivers are not supported anymore and now I just want to try everything before I really switch to 14.04.

With the pre-installed drivers the iGPU seems to work fine. I can brows (without VSYNC....), I can watch in-browser videos up to 1080p@60 or 1440p, I can play Minecraft with 30-60 FPS. So es, basically the iGPU is working.

`DRI_PRIME=1` just does nothing. Also this notebook has a nice LED showing which GPU is running, and it shows the internal one. Never switches to orange.

Funny though: When I use this command to start `glxgears`, the dGPU shows thousands of frames, while the iGPU stays at ~59.6.

Then I tried
1. https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers
2. https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa/
3. https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa

1. crashes with the dGPU on boot, then boots up with the iGPU. iGPU works fine. When I use `DRI_PRIME=1` it crashes. glxgears crashes with `radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:`, Minecraft crashes. The orange LED lights up for a second and stops again.
2. is the experimental one, bleeding edge. But it works best for me O-o It boots without failure, but then does the same like 1. Crash, when I address `DRI_PRIME=1`
3. doesn't boot. Crashes with lots of AMD errors. Only boots in safe mode.

Did I miss something? Should I install some fancy switchable graphics tool?

Btw the only propietary driver I've got is this:
`driver   : amd64-microcode - distro non-free`

The error I get when those applications crash is:

```
alex@Alex-GX60-3AE:~$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears -info
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000000800000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x800000
radeon: Failed to allocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    alignment : 4096 bytes
radeon:    domains   : 4
radeon:    va        : 0x0000000000800000
radeon: Failed to deallocate virtual address for buffer:
radeon:    size      : 65536 bytes
radeon:    va        : 0x800000
radeonsi: Failed to create a context.
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Any ideas? On Windows 10 I started to have problems with UWP apps and my iGPU crashing them -.- When the dGPU would start working I would keep this as my semi-gaming ubuntu notebook thing finally.....

*edit*
I've done some more testing. The vanilla open source driver just never uses the dGPU. glxgears gets more frames but I guess it's just not vsync'ed anymore. Drivers 1 and 3 don't boot normally but fail 1-2 times and then run without hardware acceleration. Sometimes my orange LED stays on all the time and I can measure the dGPU's temps, but it doesn't accelerate at all. So starting a game on steam leads to 1-2 fps. The most bleeding-edge driver, podoka's LLVM 5.0, works great with my iGPU and even manages to start the dGPU when I request it with DRI_PRIME=1, but it fails allocating the memory. I googled a lot but couldn't find much helpful information. People compile their own drivers with some flags but I don't know where to start :/ It feels like I'm really close to a working solution, but not yet there.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: [AMD-AMD Switchable GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117612/amd-amd-switchable-gpu)